# Flutter - Unwanted white rectangle/corners in elevated Card's shadow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have an elevated Card, but I get an unwanted white rectangle appearing inside the shadow of the card:

[image]

If I rotate it I get just a small white corner in the bottom right:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Card(
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    color: primaryColorMid,
    elevation: ELEVATION_2,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    ),
    child: Container(
    height: 200,
    width: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(),
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    padding:
        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 20),
    child: Stack(children: [
        Positioned(
            top: -10,
            right: -15,
            child: Icon(FontAwesome5Solid.plus,
                size: 200,
                color: primarySwatch.shade600)),
    ]),
    ),
),
```

Does anything in the code suggest that it will have that white rectangle in the shadow? Is there any fix or even hack to get rid of it? I thought that `clipBehaviour: Clip.hardEdge` would fix it. Bonus points for fixing the shadow being cut off on the right side in the bottom picture.

Comment: Is the `Card` in another widget that has a background? I copied this code and it worked perfectly here.

Comment: @Zeus Yes the code works fine in my other Cards. I have copy-pasted the code for 3 Cards, issue is only appearing on the bottom card. The card is nested in a few different custom widgets so is a lot of code to show in the question.

Comment: I think it is a flutter bug because as I add more cards and scroll down, the white rectangles move dynamically and disappear dynamically.

Comment: Hmm..Can you add the code for the Scrolling widget?

Comment: `Expanded(
flex: 4,
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Container(
padding:
const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: PAD_2),
child: Card(...`

Comment: @Zeus I have updated my comment above without KeyboardAvoider so you can use. The issue is still there.